# NSPredicate returning empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, filter, nspredicate

I am attempting to filter an array of 'channels' to find only the channels who's type property is 'Twitter'. However, my attempt to filter the array with NSPredicate returns an empty array. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *officials = [decodedData valueForKey:@"officials"];
NSMutableArray *channels = [officials valueForKey:@"channels"];
NSLog(@"%@", channels);


NSPredicate *twitterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = 'Twitter'"];
NSLog(@"%@", [channels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:twitterPredicate]);
```

This is my return before and after the predicate is applied:

Before:

```
 (
    (
            {
        id = SenatorFeinstein;
        type = Facebook;
    },
            {
        id = SenFeinstein;
        type = Twitter;
    },
            {
        id = SenatorFeinstein;
        type = YouTube;
    }
),
    (
            {
        id = senatorboxer;
        type = Facebook;
    },
            {
        id = SenatorBoxer;
        type = Twitter;
    },
            {
        id = SenatorBoxer;
        type = YouTube;
    }
),
```

)

After:

```
2015-01-07 10:19:31.760 voices[537:66850] ()
```

Is there something wrong with my predicate filter? I am using the Google Civic API for iOS. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: The problem is you have two array inside your channels array.

Comment: Looks like you have an array containing two arrays that each contain three dictionaries. Your predicate is probably only filtering the top array and not finding any matches because the elements it is filtering (the arrays) do not provide that key. You'll want to change your logic to filter the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it get all your dict from the arrays inside the channel array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *officials =[decodedData valueForKey:@"officials"];
NSMutableArray *channels = [officials valueForKey:@"channels"];
NSLog(@"%@", channels);

NSMutableArray *onlyChannels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *array in channels)
{
    for (NSDictionary  *dict in array)
    {
        [onlyChannels addObject:dict];
    }
}


NSPredicate *twitterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = 'Twitter'"];
NSLog(@"%@", [onlyChannels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:twitterPredicate]);
```